# API how to use Post QueryString

Tags: rest-assured

Rest assured - API how to use post query string I am unable to pass this. I have to check or uncheck manually.

Instead send data from media type we need to send data with Post query string:

```
 response = given()
.header()
.log()
.when()
.post()
.then()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's just content-type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

For example:

```
given().log().all()
        .config(RestAssured.config()
                        .encoderConfig(encoderConfig().appendDefaultContentCharsetToContentTypeIfUndefined(false)))
      .contentType(ContentType.URLENC)
      .formParam("name", "john.smith")
      .formParam("firstName", "john")
      .formParam("lastName", "Smith")
      .formParam("email", "js@jscompany.com")
      .post("https://postman-echo.com/post")
      .prettyPrint();
```